# Using Copy feature from postgresql with ftp server

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, ftp, ftp-server

I need to use copy query from postgresql, my copy query is below (i run it with php)

```
create temp table tmp_food (like food); -- create temporary table like food

copy tmp_food from 'd:\testingfood.csv' delimiter '|' csv;  -- copy to temp table

insert into food (food_id, food_name)   -- insert into food from temp table
select food_id, food_name
from tmp_food
on conflict (food_id) do                -- update instead of error
update set food_name = excluded.food_name;

drop table tmp_food;                    -- drop temp table
```

But the thing is, i need to copy it from ftp server so i need to change this line

> copy tmp_food from 'ftp\somefolder' delimiter '|' csv;  -- copy to temp table

btw this is my code to read csv, but the thing i need is get the path and combine it to my php

```
$ftp_server = "127.0.0.1";
$ftp_username = "alex";
$ftp_userpass = "alex";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
echo "success connect to FTP";
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
echo $contents;

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Comment: you will need to copy csv to local directory first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the following options:

- Read the file into a PHP array and use [`pg_copy_from`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php) to load it to the temporary table using PostgreSQL `COPY FROM STDIN`.
- Write a function in a powerful language like [PL/PerlU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) that performs the file transfer for you prior to executing `COPY`.